Getting 'No credentials were found in the store' error from Auth0 iOS SDK
'No credentials were found in the store' error is thrown from iOS Auth0 SDK while trying to refresh Token.
This is a random issue. Not able to reproduce the actual scenario for this. But Observed Server logs for this issue happening for multiple users.
Code is as below
        let publisher = self.credentialsManager.credentials(minTTL: Constants.minimumTTL)
            .map { [weak self] _ in
        
                Log.authentication.info("auth - refresh token successful")
                return true
            }
            .mapError { [weak self] error in
                self?.credentials = nil
                Log.authentication.error("auth - refresh token failed: %@", error.debugDescription)

            }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .handleEvents(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in

            })
            .share()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

The response block comes with enum .noCredentials and message "No credentials were found in the store"

There is no refresh token. The app could have been restored from back up or transferred to a new device. Is it possible that you are trying to access the refresh token while the keychain is locked (ie before first unlock?) You need to get the user to log in again.
